# Proving triangle inequality for general vectors.

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, triangle-inequality

If we assume Cauchy-swarz $|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\ge |\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|$, is the following proof for triangle inequality correct?

$$|\vec{u}+\vec{v}|^2 = |\vec{u}|^2+|\vec{v}|^2+2(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})$$
$$(|\vec{u}|+|\vec{v}|)^2=|\vec{u}|^2+|\vec{v}|^2+2|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|$$
since $|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\ge |\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|\Rightarrow |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\ge (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})$
$$|\vec{u}|^2+|\vec{v}|^2+2(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})\le |\vec{u}|^2+|\vec{v}|^2+2|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|$$
$$\Leftrightarrow |\vec{u}+\vec{v}|^2\le (|\vec{u}|+|\vec{v}|)^2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow |\vec{u}+\vec{v}|\le (|\vec{u}|+|\vec{v}|)$$

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to be better at proof writing and am just getting started, so I am concerned that I write it poorly.